# Select Into WHERE

Tags: sql

I'm currently in the process of merging two tables in my DB. I'm trying to use this code:

```
    INSERT INTO starinformation( pageX, pageY ) 
SELECT pageX, pageY
FROM starmaptopdown
WHERE starID = starinformation.starID
```

but the code isn't working. The query is exucuting saying that all the tables were effected, but the information was not placed into the database/

Answer (score 3):

The `select` query on an `insert` cannot be correlated with the table being inserted.  I'm guessing that you want an `update` and not an `insert`.  The exact format for this varies by database.  In MySQL, the syntax is:

```
update startinformation i join
       starmaptopdown md
       on i.startID = md.startID
    set i.pageX = md.pageX,
        i.pageY = md.pageY;
```

In SQL Server and Postgres:

```
update startinformation 
    set pageX = md.pageX,
        pageY = md.pageY
    from startinformation join
         starmaptopdown md
          on i.startID = md.startID;
```